# Flutter: iOS app Architectures x86_64 fatal error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

```
fatal error: lipo: -extract x86_64 specified but fat file: /Users/chetankaushik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnmgwtauvmtmtidrwcvlkprknnlo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App does not contain that architecture
Failed to extract x86_64 for /Users/chetankaushik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnmgwtauvmtmtidrwcvlkprknnlo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App. Running lipo -info:
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/chetankaushik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gnmgwtauvmtmtidrwcvlkprknnlo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App are: armv7 arm64
```

Flutter app shows this error on running.

Comment: This is my xcode build settings page.
![img](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14369357/44997089-51c5b980-afc9-11e8-8ddd-0721652f1e60.png)

Comment: What command produces that error? What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: `flutter run `
this command to run the app

Comment: Flutter (Channel dev, v0.7.5, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-IN)

Comment: I've tried channel master and beta.. no results with them.

Comment: Phone or emulator?

Comment: If you create a new project with `flutter create` and then run `flutter run`, does this work or fail as well?

Comment: I created a new flutter project and used the same code it worked on both simulator and the phone.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion